# Dragon game not working, says defined variable is undefined

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am making a game that has you choose from three caves, and each one has a dragon in it. When I run this program, it refuses to run, and says that potatocave is undefined. I am using python 3. I need to know why it will not accept potatocave as defined, what I am doing wrong, and if there is a simpler way of doing this.

EDIT: I ran it again and it says that chosenCave is undefined.
Traceback error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Projects\Dragon.py", line 32, in <module>
    if chosenCave == str(friendlyCave):
NameError: name 'chosenCave' is not defined
```

```
import random
import time
time.sleep (3)
def displayIntro():
    print('You are in a land full of dragons. In front of you,')
    print('you see three caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly')
    print('and will share his treasure with you. Another dragon')
    print('is greedy and hungry, and will eat you on sight.')
    print('The last dragon is a Potarian and gives free potatoes.')

def chooseCave():
    cave = ''
    while cave != '1' and cave != '2' and cave != '3':
        print('Which cave will you go into? (1, 2 or 3)')
        cave = input()

    return cave

def checkCave(chosenCave):
    print('You approach the cave...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('It is dark and spooky...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and...')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

friendlyCave = random.randint(1, 3)
potatocave = random.randint(1, 3)
while potatocave == friendlyCave:
    potatocave = random.randint(1, 3)
if chosenCave == str(friendlyCave):
    print('Gives you his treasure!')
elif chosenCave == str(potatocave):
    print ('Millions of potatoes rain from the sky.')
else:
    print('Gobbles you down in one bite!')

playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'y':

    displayIntro()

    caveNumber = chooseCave()

    checkCave(caveNumber)

    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
```

P.S This was not the final version, I just used a potato cave as a placeholder to figure out the concept of three caves instead of my original two.

Comment: if you still have the error post the traceback too :) so that we can see at which line it says so :)

Comment: Your indentation looks off.  Is that really how it looks in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the error message says it all: you haven't defined `chosenCave` by the moment you are trying to compare it to `str(friendlyCave)`, i.e. line 32.

---

Just imagine you're the interpreter and work through your script from the beginning. Your course of action would be:

1. `import random`, `import time`, `sleep for 3 seconds`;
   as a result, `random` and `time` are now recognized names.
2. define functions `displayIntro`, `chooseCave`, `checkCave`; those are now also known names referring to the respective functions.
3. assign `friendlyCave` and `potatocave`. Reassign the latter in a loop.
4. compare `chosenCave` to `str(friendlyCave)`... wait, what `chosenCave`?

---

But, as DSM notes, if lines 28-37 were indented as part of the body of `checkCave` function, everything would work just fine:

```
def checkCave(chosenCave):
    print('You approach the cave...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('It is dark and spooky...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and...')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

    friendlyCave = random.randint(1, 3)
    potatocave = random.randint(1, 3)
    while potatocave == friendlyCave:
        potatocave = random.randint(1, 3)
    if chosenCave == str(friendlyCave):
        print('Gives you his treasure!')
    elif chosenCave == str(potatocave):
        print ('Millions of potatoes rain from the sky.')
    else:
        print('Gobbles you down in one bite!')
```

Comment: @Lev: that's why I was asking after the indentation -- I get the feeling that from friendly-to-gobbles should be one level to the right, but the first version said that *potatocave* was the one undefined and that was really puzzling..

Comment: @DSM Luckily for me, at the moment I was reading this question there was a  traceback matching the code in it :) But yeah, the potatocave error must be from another version of the code

Comment: Yes, it was. Sorry for not saying that potatocave was no longer a problem, I am new both to coding, and to Stack Overflow, so I make a lot of stupid mistakes.